# How to access textbox value from a gridview ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Using C#, I am trying to access the value of a textbox defined within an `ItemTemplate` inside a `GridView`. That is, trying to get to an item such as:

```
<GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <TextBox ID="NotesInput" runat="server" Width="130px"></TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</GridTemplateColumn>
```

There are no events fired or no need to edit, just need to access it. The other columns are bound to database fields but this is a value that is entered, and needs to be processed. Can you please provide some guidance ?

Comment: <GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <TextBox ID="NotesInput" runat="server" Width="130px"></RadTextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                        </GridTemplateColumn>

Comment: If you can, edit your question and put the information from your comment into the question where it belongs.

Comment: Access where? On the presentation layer via JavaScript or in the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

you can find textbox like this

```
var txt = (TextBox)YourGridName.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtboxID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it directly from code since it is in a gridview you'll have to select a row and then find the control you need.

```
TextBox notesInput = (TextBox)gridName.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("NotesInput");
```